# Should I upgrade the version installed with OS X Yosemite?

Tags: openssl

I am new to using Openssl and am wondering whether it is always best to upgrade it to the latest version available or whether this might cause problems.

In most cases I would not hesitate to install the newest version of any given software product but in this case I am wondering why software installed automatically together with Yosemite is not automatically updated to the latest version.

So: is it possible to recommend that I update (or do not update) to the latest version or is this one of those questions where the answer begins with "it depends"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You are correct @jww. I should have given it more consideration where to ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely not upgrade the system provided version of OpenSSL, because it can break all applications depending on the exact version provided (ABI included).

I don't know what you mean by user (the command line tool or the library), but if you need an updated version of OpenSSL (or many other Open Source software) you should look at [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: Thank you, @Mathias Brossard. I guess I could just install the newest version of openssl in a separate folder. Do you have any thoughts on whether the newest version of openssl is superior to the one installed natively with Yosemite (is says version 0.9.8zd, built on Mar 19 2015). I am wondering whether the native version is a Apple customized version ....

Comment: @David - see [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. By default, the library uses `/usr/local/ssl`. If you configure with `--openssldir=/usr/local`, the `openssl` program will go in `/usr/local/bin`, while the libraries will go in `/usr/local/lib`.